# Take the difference of each value from the value before it in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have csv file has values like this in one column:

```
1
9
5
7
3
```

How can I compute the difference between :

```
1-0=1   #(A1)
9-1=8   #(A2-A1)
5-2=3   #(A3-A2)
7-3=4   #(A4-A3)
3-7= -4  #(A5-A4)
```

This is the result :

```
1 8 3 4 -4
```

and put the result in the second column for the same csv file ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you read the csv? The algorithm seems relatively straightforward here.

Comment: "How can I compute the difference between :and put the result in the second column for the same csv file ?"

Comment: Again, your precise problem is not clear. Can you please elaborate on what, exactly is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {'Numbers' : [234,-435,38,56,-4567,34,998]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['diff'] = df['Numbers'].rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1] - x.iloc[0]).fillna(df.Numbers.iloc[0])
```

First row will be NaN so to avoid that add fillna to zero

**Output:**

```
   Numbers    diff
0      234   234.0
1     -435  -669.0
2       38   473.0
3       56    18.0
4    -4567 -4623.0
5       34  4601.0
6      998   964.0
```

Comment: There's already a built-in for this, `df['Numbers'].diff().fillna(df['Numbers'])`

Comment: Or alternatively, `df['Numbers'] - df['Numbers'].shift(1, fill_value=0)`

Comment: I do not know this method. First thing comes to my mind is rolling window. Anyway thanks for commenting. 
Why don't you put it as solution. Your method looks clean

Comment: Because this question is not adequately specified, and should probably be closed

Comment: Thank you @Midhilesh Momidi, but I need to deal with csv file. Can you see the update?

Comment: @oleva Read that csv file as Dataframe and do the above methods.